# Buttons not appearing after changing view

Tags: asp.net, background-image, multiview

I currently am having an issue with my buttons and other controls not appearing on the page after changing the view. The program is set up like this:

1. The user inputs a number in a textbox (tbxNumber)
2. the user clicks the button (btnNumber), and the button populates a drop down list (ddlViews) with "views". The amount of views depends on the number inputted.
3. the user picks a view from the drop down list, and clicks another button. the button switches to whichever view corresponds with the views in multiview (mtvNumber).

I have the program switching to the right views, but when it switches the buttons, textbox, and dropdownlist all disappear. Is this the right way to change the background of a view in asp.net?

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mtvNumber" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex ="-1">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
              <img src='Images/Patriots.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
        </div>
    <p>Hello from view1</p>

    </asp:View>
```

I'm not sure if that is the correct way to set an image as the background. If anybody else has another way to bring in the picture please let me know!

ASP.Net Code

```
<div>
    <form id="formViews" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNumber" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnNumber_Click" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlViews" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlViews_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnChangeView" runat="server" Text="Change View" OnClick="BtnChangeView_Click" />
    <asp:MultiView ID="mtvNumber" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex ="-1">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
              <img src='Images/Patriots.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
        </div>
    <p>Hello from view1</p>

    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
              <img src='Images/patriots2.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
        </div>
    </asp:View>
```

C# Code

```
 protected void BtnChangeView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // string used to check input.
    string viewChecker = ddlViews.SelectedValue.ToString();

    // if view1 is selected, switch to view1
    if (viewChecker == "view1")
    {
        mtvNumber.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        Response.Write("made it to the first view");
        BtnChangeView.Visible = true;
        btnNumber.Visible = true;

        // if view2 is selected, switch to view2
    }
    else if (viewChecker == "view2")
    {
        mtvNumber.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        Response.Write("made it to the second view");
    }
    // if view3 is selected, switch to view3
    else if (viewChecker == "view3")
    {
        mtvNumber.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
        Response.Write("made it to the third view");
    }
```

Comment: I guess im missing something, can you please post some more code?

Comment: just posted it!

Comment: any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the styling your applying to the image? Try this and see if the view changes and your other controls are still there.

```
<div>
    <form id="formViews" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNumber" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnNumber_Click" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlViews" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlViews_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnChangeView" runat="server" Text="Change View" OnClick="BtnChangeView_Click" />
    <asp:MultiView ID="mtvNumber" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex ="-1">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <h2>Patriots View 1</h2>
              <img src='Images/Patriots.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
        </div>
    <p>Hello from view1</p>

    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <div>
          <h2>Patriots View 2</h2>
              <img src='Images/patriots2.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
        </div>
    </asp:View>
```